# Should Nodes be compared directly or they must be going through ID() first?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query in which it lists out all files that have at least one connection to another department. Currently, this can be done in 2 ways as followed:

- Compare nodes directly.

```
MATCH (d1:Department)-[:BELONG_TO]-(n1:File)-[:DATA_LINK]-(n2:File)-[:BELONG_TO]-(d2:Department)
WHERE d1 <> d2
RETURN n1.name
```

- Compare nodes through `ID()`.

```
MATCH (d1:Department)-[:BELONG_TO]-(n1:File)-[:DATA_LINK]-(n2:File)-[:BELONG_TO]-(d2:Department)
WHERE ID(d1) <> ID(d2)
RETURN n1.name
```

**The query result so far is the same**. The first way looks neater but the second one looks stricter.

The question is: is there any performance difference in either of the approaches, especially the first one? E.g. Neo4j might hash the nodes' properties before comparing. But applying micro-optimization, Neo4j may compile all of them to the same execution plan as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing 2 nodes for (in)equality is effectively the same as comparing them by native ID. The performance difference, if any, should be insignificant.

Comment: True! To add some context, within an executing query, a node variable is a lightweight structure for the node (properties aren't projected until accessed or when returning the node). Its id() is readily available, and is used during comparison with other nodes.