# Passing domain object as argument to custom Cypher query in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm writing Spring Data Neo4j webapp.
I have this domain object:

```java
@Node("Person")
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
```

and a `(:Image) - [:DEPICTS] -> (:Person)` relationship.

I need to count images depicting specific person.
This was my attempt:

```java
public interface ImageRepositoryNeo4j extends Neo4jRepository<Image, String> {
@Query("""
        MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person)
        WHERE p = $person
        RETURN count(i)
        """)
    // DSNT WORK
    public Integer countByPeopleContains(@Param("person") Person person);
```

but it always returns 0.

### Other failed attempts

```java
@Query("""
        MATCH (i:Image)-[:DEPICTS]->(p:Person)
        WHERE p IN $people
        RETURN count(i)
        """)
    // DOESN'T WORK, 0 RESULTS
    public Integer countByPeopleContains(@Param("people") Collection<Person> people);

@Query("""
        MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person)
        WHERE ID(p) = $person.__id__
        RETURN count(i)
        """)
    // DSNT WORK
    public Integer countByPeopleContains(@Param("person") Person person);

@Query("""
        MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person)
        WHERE id(p)=$person
        RETURN count(i)
        """)
    // DSNT WORK
    public Integer countByPeopleContains(@Param("person") String personId);

@Query("""
        MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person {id: $person.__id__})
        RETURN count(i)
        """)
    // DSNT WORK, ALWAYS 0
    public Integer countByPeopleContains(@Param("person") Person person);
```

All of them return 0.

And this one works, but since `fullName` isn't unique property, it is not suitable by domain logic:

```java
@Query("""
        MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person {fullName: $person})
        RETURN count(i)
        """)
    // TODO: personFullname is not unique, use smth else
    public Integer countByPeopleContains(@Param("person") String personFullName);
```

How do I use domain object in custom Cypher query in Spring Data Neo4j Repository?

### Clue

In [Spring Data Neo4j documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/appendix/custom-queries.html#custom-queries.parameters) closest what I've found to what I need is this:

```java
@Node
public final class Movie {

    @Id
    private final String title;
...
interface MovieRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Movie, String> {

    @Query("MATCH (m:Movie {title: $movie.__id__})\n"
           + "MATCH (m) <- [r:DIRECTED|REVIEWED|ACTED_IN] - (p:Person)\n"
           + "return m, collect(r), collect(p)")
    Movie findByMovie(@Param("movie") Movie movie);
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't work in my case. Maybe that's because my id is `@GeneratedValue`.

### Another clue

In [Neo4j embedded docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/query-parameters/) there is an example on how to pass an object to Cypher without Spring Data Neo4j:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put( "node", bobNode );

String query =
    "MATCH (n:Person)" + "\n" +
    "WHERE n = $node" + "\n" +
    "RETURN n.name";

Result result = transaction.execute( query, params );
```

It works wif $node is `org.neo4j.graphdb.Node`:

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner countForGregWithoutSDN(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {
    return args -> {
        try (var tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx()) {
            String cypherGetGreg = "MATCH (n:Person {birthday: date('1993-03-03')}) RETURN n LIMIT 5;";
            Result result = tx.execute(cypherGetGreg);
            var greg1993 = (Node) result.next().get("n");
            if (!greg1993.getProperty("name").equals("Greg")) 
                throw new RuntimeException("Should be Greg1993 but actually "+greg1993);
            result.close();

            Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put( "node", greg1993 );

            String cypherCountForGreg = """
                MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person)
                WHERE p = $node
                RETURN count(i)
                """;
            result = tx.execute( cypherCountForGreg, params );
            var count = result.next().values().iterator().next();
            System.out.println("Count for Greg1993 is "+count); // 1
            result.close();
        }
    };
}
```

but it results in 0 if $node is SDN Entity.

Comment: Is `$person` a node or a property?

Comment: @Vincent It is a node.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies in evaluating node equality.

Instead of `WHERE p = $person` try `WHERE id(p) = id($person)`

UPDATE: Based on this post, I could be mistaken:
[Should Nodes be compared directly or they must be going through ID() first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844124/should-nodes-be-compared-directly-or-they-must-be-going-through-id-first)

Comment: I've tried, when this method is invoked this runtime exception is thrown: `org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input for function 'id()': Expected Map{__labels__ -> List{String("Person")}, __id__ -> String("4:21f6f6f2-ea32-4b8c-a8a7-e953f6f436c2:1559"), __properties__ -> Map{birthday -> NO_VALUE, dotId -> String("somedotid"), fullName -> String("vasya pupkin")}} to be a node or relationship, but it was 'Map'`

Comment: `$person` isn't a node then, not in the way Neo4j needs it to be. Do you have to pass in your Person node object, or could you just have a PersonID as an indexed property on the node?

Comment: It is a node. It is an object of a class annotated with `@Node`, it was returned from neo4jRepository and as you can see in the exception SDN added `__labels__` and `__id__` properties, and latter is neo4j-generated. If needed, I can provide MRE. I haven't found any working example of what I'm trying to do anywhere. I can change signature of this method and pass a `person.id` String, but it doesn't work either (see "failed attempts") and also `id()` func is deprecated and neo4j team discourages usage of internal node ids.

Comment: You're right about `id()`. As for the class, the error says that whole thing is a map, not a node or relationship, and I'm not sure how that happens. You could try `p =  apoc.convert.toNode($person)` or `apoc.create.vNode($person)`. Otherwise, an MRE would be really useful.

Comment: here you go, [MRE](https://gist.github.com/Podbrushkin/54518ad6c4835706fd3344f01ea6acc9). I hope recreating directory structure wouldn't take much time, usually I do it in pwsh like that: `gcb -Raw | New-Item -Force '.\src\main\java\myapp\repo\PersonRepositoryNeo4j.java'` etc. Run it with `mvn clean spring-boot:run -e`.  Thank you for your attention. If we could reference our entity object in custom cypher without relying on id, it would be very good. But right now I can't do it even through id.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of passing fields.

**Note:** I used Spring Boot 3.2, SDN v7.2.2 and Neo4j v5.

1. Use a Map without saving the Node:

**Model:**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Node
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Property(name = "model")
    private String model;

    public Car(){} // have an empty constructor to save
}
```

**Repository class:**

```
public interface CarRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Car, Long> {
    
    @Query("WITH $car AS c " +
            "RETURN c['model'] AS model")
    String getCarModel(@Param("car") Map<String, Object> carMap); 
}
```

**Testing:**

```
 private void testCar() {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setModel("Tesla Model S");

        Map<String, Object> carMap = new HashMap<>();
        carMap.put("model", car.getModel());
        String model = carRepository.getCarModel(carMap);
        System.out.println("\nModel: " + model);

    }
```

2. Save the Node and use Id to access the parameters

**Repository:**
The important part is to use `__id__` here. "*.id*" did not work in tests.

```
 public interface CarRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Car, Long> {
        @Query("MATCH (c:car) WHERE id(c) = $car.__id__ " +
                "RETURN c.model as model")
        String getCarModel(@Param("car") Car car);
    }
```

**Testing:**

```
    private void testCar() {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setModel("Tesla Model S");
    
        carRepository.save(car); //this will save it with an ID
        System.out.println("\nModel: " + 
        carRepository.getCarModel(car));
        carRepository.delete(car);//if you want
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your Cypher doesn't use any data from db at all. It's like `return 1+1`. It doesn't depend on a state of any Car node in db. Also you are using a property which is not an Id of an entity object. I believe you can pass and reference plain properties to repo method as they are, without Map, like I did with fullName. I.e. you can query for all Cars with model=Tesla. My question is about uniquely identifying domain object in cypher. I.e. query for all owners of a particular Car obj you've passed as an arg to repo.

Comment: yes, the idea was to be able to pass the object's fields but I updated my response for the version that gives you an "id" to be used to access the node's values. This version uses the actual DB data.

Comment: It looks better, but also it looks pretty much like what've tried in "Other failed attempts" #2. I am sure I was passing a person which was extracted from db just before that, therefore it had a valid id. Probably caveat is in type of id - my String vs your Long. I think your test will fail if you change id type from Long to String. Maybe you will have to substring car.id before looking for it in db.

Comment: well, the point here is to pass the object, save it as a node, and use its field(s) in the later parts of the query. I am not worried about the type of id at this point. What I have there is doing it without failing. I am sure it will be useful for some.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```java
public interface ImageRepositoryNeo4j extends Neo4jRepository<Image, String> {
@Query("""
    MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person)
    WHERE id(p) = toInteger(split($person.__id__, ':')[-1])
    RETURN count(i)
    """)
public Integer countImagesDepictingPerson(@Param("person") Person person);
```

Ugly, but it works. Note: Person.id is of type String. Maybe you wouldn't need all this hassle if your Person.id is of type Integer or Long.

### Explanation

When we have

```java
@Node("Person")
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
```

This is what exactly neo4j generates as an id:

```java
var freshPerson = personRepository.findOneByBirthday(LocalDate.of(1993,3,3));
log.info("freshPerson.getId()={}", freshPerson.getId());
// freshPerson.getId()=4:a8bd1c80-0f61-4a2b-b094-7e7aed736caf:2
```

As you can see, freshPerson.id is a long string.

But if you will call this cypher:

```java
@Query("""
    MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Roy'})
    RETURN id(p)
    """)
public Integer getRoyIdInt();
```

You will get an Integer (and a warning message about `id()` function being deprecated).

And if you will call this cypher:

```java
@Query("""
    MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Roy'})
    RETURN p.id
    """)
public String getRoyId();
```

You will get null instead of String and this warning:

```
WARN 7164 --- [           main] o.s.data.neo4j.cypher.unrecognized       : Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.UnknownPropertyKeyWarning: The provided property key is not in the database
        MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Roy'})
        RETURN p.id
                 ^
    One of the property names in your query is not available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you run this statement in your application (the missing property name is: id)
```

This is unexpected, because obviously we have `id` property in our Person class, even though it is annotated with `@Id @GeneratedValue`.

Integer in the end of `4:a8bd1c80-0f61-4a2b-b094-7e7aed736caf:2` is actually what `id()` function returns, so we can extract it and find a node by it. This is exactly what is happening in Solution section.

Also we can extract it in java, check out last section. I've made it verbose so it will be clear what is going on.

### Solution 2

Declare neo4j repo method which takes Integer as an arg:

```java
@Query("""
    MATCH (i:Image) -[:DEPICTS] -> (p:Person)
    WHERE id(p) = $id
    RETURN count(i)
    """)
public Integer countImagesDepictingPersonWithId(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

Use this method:

```java
// Create Greg with birthday:
Person greg = new Person("Greg", LocalDate.of(1993,3,3));
greg = personRepository.save(greg);

// Create image depicting Greg:
var img2 = new Image("/blabla2.jpg");
img2.getPeople().add(greg);

// Find someone by birthday (we know it's Greg):
var freshPerson = personRepository.findOneByBirthday(LocalDate.of(1993,3,3));

// Extract Integer id from String id:
String[] tokens = freshPerson.getId().split(":");
String lastToken = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
Integer gregId = Integer.parseInt(lastToken);

// Count images depicting Greg:
var count = imageRepository.countImagesDepictingPersonWithId(gregId);
log.info("Greg1993 is depicted in {} images.", count); //1
```

We just moved String splitting logic from Cypher to Java.